# TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [stuff] of type str

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have sorted df:

```
d
    cost    margin
Date        
2018-12-28  -0.000351   0.006714
2021-04-27  -0.000618   0.011988
2021-07-06  -0.000806   0.006352
2021-02-02  -0.000825   0.017305
2018-11-28  -0.000831   0.004580
2021-05-18  -0.001560   0.004649
2019-04-15  -0.001607   0.003223
2019-02-21  -0.002103   0.006027
2019-08-09  -0.002264   0.008437
```

What i want to do is, to add row 1 and everything before it for both `cost` and `margin` and then row 2,1 and then row 3,2,1. So sum every row with everything before it till the end. To do this i have this :

```
for stuff in range(len(d)):
    for data in d.iloc[1:'stuff']:
        print(data)
```

But i am not even able to get the iterated data here and am getting this error:

> TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on DatetimeIndex with these
> indexers [stuff] of type str

Could you please advise what i can do to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the quotes around `stuff` allows your code to run :

```py
for stuff in range(len(d)):
    for data in d.iloc[1:stuff]:
        print(data)
```

However, we can reach your goal simply by using the `cumsum()` method on both columns `cost` and `margin` like so :

```py
>>> d[['cost_sum', 'margin_sum']] = d[['cost', 'margin']].cumsum()
>>> d
    Date             cost     margin     cost_sum   margin_sum
0   2018-12-28  -0.000351   0.006714    -0.000351   0.006714
1   2021-04-27  -0.000618   0.011988    -0.000969   0.018702
2   2021-07-06  -0.000806   0.006352    -0.001775   0.025054
3   2021-02-02  -0.000825   0.017305    -0.002600   0.042359
4   2018-11-28  -0.000831   0.004580    -0.003431   0.046939
5   2021-05-18  -0.001560   0.004649    -0.004991   0.051588
6   2019-04-15  -0.001607   0.003223    -0.006598   0.054811
7   2019-02-21  -0.002103   0.006027    -0.008701   0.060838
8   2019-08-09  -0.002264   0.008437    -0.010965   0.069275
```